# UISwipeRecognizer and it's associated object

Tags: ios, objective-c

So i've been looking at how to use a swipe recogniser but i'm a bit stuck.

I've used the Interface builder to attach a swipe gesture recogniser to one of my many textfields.

I then want to clear the contents of the textfield if a right swipe is recognised. I then want to add the swipe gesture recogniser to all of the textfields and then associate the same method to all of the gesture recognisers.

Unfortunately, I don't know how a gesture recogniser handles information relating to the object it's associated to.

How do I write a method that refers to the associated textfield?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a property that contains the view it's attached to. Read it and cast it to you UITextField.

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIView *view
```

Like this:

```
- (IBAction)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {    
    UITextField *field = (UITextField*)recognizer.view;
    ....
}
```